# Spring custom security check in SecurityConfiguration

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm currently working on an application with a lot of REST endpoints to manage all kinds of things related to a company (stock, sales, deliveries, orders, ...).

For almost every call to the API I pass a RequestHeader containing the company ID. Then I then need to check if the logged in user is a member of that company. I already store these companyIds in the SecurityContext, so a check isn't that hard per se.

My question is now, what is a good approach to implement this verification. Ideally I handle this in the SecurityConfigurationConfig with a custom check, like this:

```
  .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated().isMemberOfCompany()
```

But I'm not able to figure out how to do this. The check would need to read out a request header, and verify it with a companies array in the SecurityContext.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is to create a custom web filter with your authorization logic and add it to the http security configuration, like this :

```
 .antMatchers("/api/**")
 .authenticated()
 .and()
 .addFilterAfter(new CustomFilter(), SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION)
```

The custom filter should implement the WebFilter interface :

```
public class CustomFilter implements WebFilter {

@Override
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
    final SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
    // authorization logic
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @lucas-declercq, I tried doing this, but the addFilterAfter requires different parameters for me.

`public HttpSecurity addFilterAfter(Filter filter, Class<? extends Filter> afterFilter) {
        return this.addFilterAtOffsetOf(filter, 1, afterFilter);
    }`